# Error al crear tabla: "An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified"

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo problemas al intentar ejecutar el script para crear la tabla cliente, les dejo el código y las tablas con las que interactúa junto a su respectivo problema.

TABLA CLIENTE

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
RUT VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTE PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOP VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_APELLIDOP_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
APELLIDOM VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT NOTNNULL_APELLIDOM_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
DIRECCION VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_DIRECCION_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
TELEFONO NUMBER(8) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_TELEFONO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(255) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_EMAIL_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
SEXO CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_SEXO_CLIENTE NOT NULL,
CIUDAD_COD_CIUDAD NUMBER CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_CIUDAD_COD_CIUAD NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_CIUDAD FOREIGN KEY(CIUDAD_COD_CIUDAD) REFERENCES CIUDAD(COD_CIUDAD)
);
```

TABLA CIUDAD

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_CIUDAD PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE_CIUDAD VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_CIUDAD NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_REGION NOT NULL
);
```

ERROR ARROJADO POR SQL DEVELOPER (versión 17xxx).

```
Informe de error 
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle no acepta identificadores que sean más largos de 30 caracteres, como bien explica el mensaje de error que recibes.

En este caso, parece ser el nombre del constraint `NOTNULL_FECHA_NACIMIENTO_CLIENTE`. Si modificas el nombre del constraint para que sea más corto, no deberías tener problema.

Nota: A partir de Oracle 12.2, los identificadores pueden llegar hasta 128 caracteres.

Comment: Excelente me funciono!, ese era el error, muchas gracias.